# If two videos with the same source stream at the same time will they have separate cache files?

Tags: cache, video-streaming

I was resolving an issue on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236480/how-can-i-show-only-a-section-of-a-video-frame-with-css-or-javascript) ([see my answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236480/how-can-i-show-only-a-section-of-a-video-frame-with-css-or-javascript/27241398#27241398)), where I might stream the same video on the same webpage in two separate video elements. I don't really understand web file caching very well, but I do understand that somehow the browser can usually tell if you've downloaded a file before, so it will show you the cached one instead to increase page load speeds.

My question is, in the scenario where there are two video elements on the same page streaming the same video at the same time, does the browser "realize" this or will it make two cache files and effectively download the video file twice? I'm thinking no, but I just want to be sure.

---

For my personal setup, I would be streaming the video file from Amason S3 or CloudFront. My site is hosted through bluehost these days.

Comment: Cleaned up my comments a bit. I'm relatively sure both would cache the video the same way. However you might want to read up on [what your site is probably going to be running under](http://www.scriptrock.com/articles/iis-apache).

Comment: @Reaces I would bet on Apache then. I'm pretty sure it's a linux server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best guess is the browser will download it twice, and any optimization avoiding the second download would be very browser specific.

However, this should be an easy enough thing to test, and I've just now done that :)

With Firefox browser and JW Player, the video is loaded twice concurrently.  Neither the browser nor flash is smart enough to optimize this corner case.

Here is what I see in Firebug:
[image: Screen shot of Firebug network tab]

The server logs also confirm two downloads:

```
X.X.X.X - - [29/Jan/2015:22:52:57 -0600] "GET /videos/PCA-MasterTradeShowa800x.f4v HTTP/1.1" 200 31818277 "http://.../videos/jwplayer/player.swf" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0 Iceweasel/31.4.0"
X.X.X.X - - [29/Jan/2015:22:52:56 -0600] "GET /videos/PCA-MasterTradeShowa800x.f4v HTTP/1.1" 200 31818277 "http://.../videos/jwplayer/player.swf" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0 Iceweasel/31.4.0"
```

---

The developer tools in Chrome seem to show two separate downloads:

[image]

Comment: Would file type matter? This is with an swf it seems. My case scenario would be mp4 html5.

Comment: My guess it'll still download it twice.  But try it and let us know what you find.

Comment: The network tab in chrome dev tools seems to only show one download of the video.

Comment: And your browser caches are cleared before testing (you see one and only one download in the server logs)?

Comment: It seems you are probably right. Cleared the cache and ran in incognito mode and I see two there.

Comment: Man, that's a real bummer. I'll have to come up with something else.